# Automatically adding img html tag when an URL is typed

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a question and I thought you guys could be able to help me out with it.

I am making a custom blog and I found on the internet a very cool php file that provided these functions

```
function _make_url_clickable_cb($matches) {
    $ret = '';
    $url = $matches[2];

    if ( empty($url) )
        return $matches[0];
    // removed trailing [.,;:] from URL
    if ( in_array(substr($url, -1), array('.', ',', ';', ':')) === true ) {
        $ret = substr($url, -1);
        $url = substr($url, 0, strlen($url)-1);
    }
    return $matches[1] . "<a href=\"$url\" rel=\"nofollow\">$url</a>" . $ret;
}
```

I would like to have a function that would automatically detect when the link posted is an image (jpg, gif, png, etc) and automatically add the img tag.

I tried changing from this, but I am not really good with regexes

```
function _make_img_tag($matches) {
$ret = '';
$url = $matches[2];

if ( empty($url) )
    return $matches[0];
if ( in_array(substr($url, -1), array('.', ',', ';', ':')) === true ) {
    $ret = substr($url, -1);
    $url = substr($url, 0, strlen($url)-1);
}
return $matches[1] . "<img src=\"$url\" width=\"800\" height=\"600\">$url" . $ret;
}
```

and then

```
$ret = preg_replace_callback('#^(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)#is', '_make_img_tag', $ret);
```

But it only shows as a link because of the other replace callbacks that have been added.

Can you guys please help me?

Thanks in advance,

edit: posting the full code

```
function _make_url_clickable_cb($matches) {
$ret = '';
$url = $matches[2];

if ( empty($url) )
    return $matches[0];
// removed trailing [.,;:] from URL
if ( in_array(substr($url, -1), array('.', ',', ';', ':')) === true ) {
    $ret = substr($url, -1);
    $url = substr($url, 0, strlen($url)-1);
}
return $matches[1] . "<a href=\"$url\" rel=\"nofollow\">$url</a>" . $ret;
}

function _make_web_ftp_clickable_cb($matches) {
$ret = '';
$dest = $matches[2];
$dest = 'http://' . $dest;

if ( empty($dest) )
    return $matches[0];
// removed trailing [,;:] from URL
if ( in_array(substr($dest, -1), array('.', ',', ';', ':')) === true ) {
    $ret = substr($dest, -1);
    $dest = substr($dest, 0, strlen($dest)-1);
}
return $matches[1] . "<a href=\"$dest\" rel=\"nofollow\">$dest</a>" . $ret;
}

function _make_email_clickable_cb($matches) {
$email = $matches[2] . '@' . $matches[3];
return $matches[1] . "<a href=\"mailto:$email\">$email</a>";
}

function _make_img_tag($matches) {
$ret = '';
$url = $matches[2];

if ( empty($url) )
    return $matches[0];
if ( in_array(substr($url, -1), array('.', ',', ';', ':')) === true ) {
    $ret = substr($url, -1);
    $url = substr($url, 0, strlen($url)-1);
}
return $matches[1] . "<img src=\"$url\" width=\"800\" height=\"600\">$url" . $ret;
}

function make_clickable($ret) {
$ret = ' ' . $ret;
$ret = preg_replace_callback('#^(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)#is', '_make_img_tag', $ret);
$ret = preg_replace_callback('#([\s>])([\w]+?://[\w\\x80-\\xff\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is', '_make_url_clickable_cb', $ret);
$ret = preg_replace_callback('#([\s>])((www|ftp)\.[\w\\x80-\\xff\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is', '_make_web_ftp_clickable_cb', $ret);
$ret = preg_replace_callback('#([\s>])([.0-9a-z_+-]+)@(([0-9a-z-]+\.)+[0-9a-z]{2,})#i', '_make_email_clickable_cb', $ret);

$ret = preg_replace("#(<a( [^>]+?>|>))<a [^>]+?>([^>]+?)</a></a>#i", "$1$3</a>", $ret);
$ret = trim($ret);
return $ret;
}
```

Comment: are you calling _make_img_tag first ?

Comment: Yes, I am. I tried changing the order.

Comment: "Good evening, " - Have you heard that the world is oblate spheroid and hence we have time zones?

Comment: you can do a simple test to check if the string begins with http and end with a image extension. i am not sure what are you doing

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a new regular expression to find the images. These two lines already find them :

```
$ret = preg_replace_callback('#([\s>])([\w]+?://[\w\\x80-\\xff\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is', '_make_url_clickable_cb', $ret);
$ret = preg_replace_callback('#([\s>])((www|ftp)\.[\w\\x80-\\xff\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is', '_make_web_ftp_clickable_cb', $ret);
```

What you need is distinguish a regular URL from an image in the functions that do the replacements. Replace

```
return $matches[1] . "<a href=\"$url\" rel=\"nofollow\">$url</a>" . $ret;
```

by

```
if (preg_match('#\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$#is', $url))
    return $matches[1] . "<img src=\"$url\" width=\"800\" height=\"600\">$url" . $ret;
else
    return $matches[1] . "<a href=\"$url\" rel=\"nofollow\">$url</a>" . $ret;
```

Comment: Why do you have fixed image width and height. If you don't know the proportions, it is better to fix only one measure. In that way you don't get distorted images. You event might want to open the image to indicate real dimensions.

Comment: That is a good question, I will remove that.
By the way, I am getting a [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_RETURN in format.php on line 14